# Greek passage in Latin Texts

Tags: errors, formatting

I need to write greek passages beetween a text in latin alphabets. Almost everytime that I search for a way I get this code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
```

To be used alongside with "/textgreek". It works by itself, but when I try to implement into my document, it shows error message for every greek character... I have no idea why this error is ocurring. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
openright,
twoside,
a5paper,
english,
latin,
greek,
brazil,
sumario=tradicional
]{abntex2}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % para mathscr

\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Scale=0.9]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Consolas}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek,french,english,spanish,german,italian}  

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\else
\usepackage{newtxmath} 
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage[lf]{FiraMono}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\fi

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,rotating}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{leading}
\leading{13pt}

\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
\ifcase #1 
Nenhuma citação no texto.
\or
Citado na página #2.
\else
Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.
\fi}

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{41,5,195}

\chapterstyle{ger}

\makepagestyle{abntbookheadings}
\makeevenhead{abntbookheadings}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida\thepage}    {}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida\textit\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{abntbookheadings}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida\textit\rightmark}    {}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida\thepage}
\makeheadrule{abntbookheadings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}

\makepagestyle{abntbookchapfirst}
\makeoddhead{abntbookchapfirst}{}{}{}

\renewcommand{\textual}{
\pagestyle{abntbookheadings}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{abntbookchapfirst}
\nouppercaseheads
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}%
}

\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\textit{miserandas} B Vat., \textit{miseranda} Cors.: as duas leituras fazem Itys o filho de sua mãe e tia. Heinsius propôs \textit{miseranda sorte}, que é muito similar a \textit{Ciris} 191 sq. 'uos, o crideli fatorum lege puellae | Dauliades'; Eu conjecturei \textit{miserandi}, com a construção de Sófoles, Édipo em Colona. 344 τἀμὰ δυστήνου κακὰ ou Ovídio, \textit{Amores}. I 8 108 'mea defunctae ossa'. Mas não sei de nenhum caso seja em Grego ou Latin de um adjetivo descritivo assim colocado, concordando com um latente genitivo, exceto quando o genitivo é latente em um pronome possessivo: as apposições em \textit{Ilíada}, v. 741 Γοργείη κεφαλὴ δεινοῖο πελώρου e Virgílio. \textit{Eneida} xii 739 'postquam arma dei ad Volcania uentum est' não são paralelos adequados.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! `Polyglossia` and `babel` do the same thing in different ways: use one or the other. You need to define a greek font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Polyglossia**

Using `polyglossia`, define a `\greekfont` and apply the font with `\textgreek`.

[image: greek in red]

MWE

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Scale=0.9]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Consolas}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek,french,english,spanish,german,italian}  
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Minion Pro}[Colour=red]

\begin{document}
\textit{miserandas} B Vat., \textit{miseranda} Cors.: as duas leituras fazem Itys o filho de sua mãe e tia. Heinsius propôs \textit{miseranda sorte}, que é muito similar a \textit{Ciris} 191 sq. 'uos, o crideli fatorum lege puellae | Dauliades'; Eu conjecturei \textit{miserandi}, com a construção de Sófoles, Édipo em Colona. 344 \textgreek{τἀμὰ δυστήνου κακὰ} ou Ovídio, \textit{Amores}. I 8 108 'mea defunctae ossa'. Mas não sei de nenhum caso seja em Grego ou Latin de um adjetivo descritivo assim colocado, concordando com um latente genitivo, exceto quando o genitivo é latente em um pronome possessivo: as apposições em \textit{Ilíada}, v. 741 \textgreek{Γοργείη κεφαλὴ δεινοῖο πελώρου} e Virgílio. \textit{Eneida} xii 739 'postquam arma dei ad Volcania uentum est' não são paralelos adequados.

\end{document}
```

**Babel**

Using `babel`, define a `\babelfont[greek]` font and apply the font with `\foreignlanguage{greek}{..}`:

[image: babel]

MWE

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Scale=0.9]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Consolas}

\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}

%\setmainlanguage{brazil}
%\setotherlanguages{latin,greek,french,english,spanish,german,italian}  
\usepackage[main=portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}[Colour=blue]{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
\textit{miserandas} B Vat., \textit{miseranda} Cors.: as duas leituras fazem Itys o filho de sua mãe e tia. Heinsius propôs \textit{miseranda sorte}, que é muito similar a \textit{Ciris} 191 sq. 'uos, o crideli fatorum lege puellae | Dauliades'; Eu conjecturei \textit{miserandi}, com a construção de Sófoles, Édipo em Colona. 344 \foreignlanguage{greek}{τἀμὰ δυστήνου κακὰ} ou Ovídio, \textit{Amores}. I 8 108 'mea defunctae ossa'. Mas não sei de nenhum caso seja em Grego ou Latin de um adjetivo descritivo assim colocado, concordando com um latente genitivo, exceto quando o genitivo é latente em um pronome possessivo: as apposições em \textit{Ilíada}, v. 741 \foreignlanguage{greek}{Γοργείη κεφαλὴ δεινοῖο πελώρου} e Virgílio. \textit{Eneida} xii 739 'postquam arma dei ad Volcania uentum est' não são paralelos adequados.

\end{document}
```

(Your document class fails on my machine, so I simplified the code.)

---

There are also alternative ways in both packages  - read the manuals (do `texdoc polyglossia` and `texdoc babel`) to see which ways you prefer.

Comment: I tried both, and it keep giving the error:

Package inputenc Error: Unicode character τ (U+03C4)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. ...ek}{τἀμὰ δυστήνου κακὰ}

Etc...

Your code works, again, by itself, and my document (with all classes) works well without the greek characters... There are something else that is preventing the greek characters to be encoded... :(

Comment: Also, if I put your full code to compile, this errors appears: "* XeTeX is required to compile this document. \RequireXeTeX" etx...

Comment: @RaphaelSoares Yes, polyglossia is for xelatex (and babel works there too): that is why inputenc is not needed. What are you compiling with?

Comment: I'm compiling with PDFLaTeX... other forms of compilation don't work (I'm using LiveTeX + TeXStudio)..

Comment: @RaphaelSoares There is `\ifxetex...\else...` in your preamble: if you must use pdflatex, then use`babel`.

Comment: Babel don't work, i tried to remove \ifxetex too, and \else, nothing works... The greek characters never appears...

Comment: @RaphaelSoares :  abntex2 works with unicode: "4.7.1  Fontes com XeLATEX Para utilizar as fontes de tipo.ttf ou.otf ..., o arquivo deve estar em co-dificação UTF8 e ser compilado com o comando xelatex (nomedoarquivo.tex).XeTEX é um programa de diagramação derivado do TEX que utiliza Unicode e possibilita o emprego de fontes tipográficas modernas.... A classe abntex2 implementa opções para XeLATEX por meio dos pacotes fontspec e polyglossia2".

Comment: @RaphaelSoares Your preamble is mixing different things together, almost randomly. Removing part of an `\if` statement won't fix things (unless you are really lucky). Who built the preamble, and what purpose and assumptions are behind it (which compilers etc)? Putting the Greek in will come almost naturally after you choose which method should be used.

Comment: @RaphaelSoares Also, the font used for Greek must have Greek characters in it.

Comment: I'm really new with the whole LaTeX thing... The preamble is the standard abntex2 model for books. I only put the "Babel" thing, because greek characters don't appers after the compilation (also, I made a "\newenvironment" too, but It doesn't affect the result, I think)... Is just the model that came with the package... XeLaTeX don't compile (I have no Idea why), and I can't make the greek characters to appear with both methods...

Comment: @RaphaelSoares (https://github.com/abntex/limarka/wiki/Configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es-avan%C3%A7adas) may help: "Escrevendo texto em grego -- Adicionar em latexcustomizacao.sty: `\usepackage{ucs}` Inclua o idioma grego (greek) no template."

Comment: @RaphaelSoares I can't get your code to run at all - it just hangs. It will take time to comment out each package/option to see what the cause is. `abntex2` is really just a style guide, so is straightforward. That leaves the possibility you might need to update your distribution.

Comment: Update the distribution was the first thing that I did, even before typing the first letter in a .tex file... The code is basically the book model (https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/blob/master/doc/latex/abntex2/examples/abntex2-modelo-livro.tex), and it works normally without any greek character (I cut out the greek phrases, to keep writing)...

Comment: Just added "\usepackage{ucs}" in the .sty file and everything worked... Thank you... @Cicada

Comment: @RaphaelSoares Good-oh. I've got Miktex and it needs to download some Texlive packages - so, two problems solved!